# iPhone iOS4 Connectivity Profiles

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to set up and easily switch connection profiles in iOS4?

i.e:

Home - Wi-Fi on, Bluetooth off, 3G off

Work - Wi-Fi off, Bluetooth off, 3G off

Car - Wi-Fi off, Bluetooth on, 3G on

etc.

Would prefer an App Store app but would consider a jailbreak app if not available.

Comment: Are you jailbroken?

Comment: The other day i saw "Locale for Android". That's way cool, but sadly there is no way to get such a thing for the iPhone (at least non-jailbroken as mine is).

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is jailbroken, [SBSettings](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/sbsettings) works really well for this. I don't think it supports profiles, but it gives quick access to toggles for all of the services you mentioned. Very helpful for the scenarios you described.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely have to jailbreak to acheive that kind of functionality.  Personally I gave @Thomas' reply a +1 because that is what I used to use.

Another option is Intelliborn's [MyProfiles Beta](http://www.intelliborn.com/products.html) - which is on sale for $7 via [Rock](http://www.rockyourphone.com/index.php/myprofiles.html?feat=y)

It *may* only support iOS 3.0.1 though.